# Delete wrong record from table

Tags: php, forms, select, html-table

I need your advice. I fetch data from database to table: ID, Name.
In table are Actions: Delete, Enable, Block. When action Delete
is selected, I would like, that respectively record will be deleted.
However, my script does not work and always delete last record, even I select 
another record. I think problem is, that select name and hidden input
name is similar for all records. But I can not find way, how to create
them with different names. 
Any advice is welcome.

HTML:

```
  <form method='post'> 
  <table border='1'>
  <tr>
  <th> ID </th>
<th> Name </th>
<th> Action </th>
</tr>
```

Code:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=****;charset=utf8', '**', '**');
$query = $db->query("SELECT ID,statusas,login,vardas,email FROM users");

while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) { 
 echo "<tr><input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row[0]."'>";
 echo "<td>".$row[0]."</td>";
 //echo "<td>".$row[1]."</td>";
 echo "<td>".$row[2]."</td>";
 //echo "<td>".$row[3]."</td>";
// echo "<td>".$row[4]."</td>";
 echo "<td><select name='action'>
             <option value='choose'>Choose..</option>
             <option value='delete'> Delete </option>
             <option value='enable'> Enable </option>
             <option value='block'> Block</option>
        </select></td>";
   echo "</tr>";
 }
 echo "<br><input type='submit' name='submit'></table></form>";

 if($_POST['submit']) {
   if ($_POST['action']== 'delete') {
   echo $_POST['id']; // delete query, but now I am just checking if I get a proper ID.
  }
}
else {
echo "bad";
}
```

[image: Table]

Comment: My guess would be that you need to wrap each row in it's own form. In its current state, all the rows are using the same form so it's simply deleting using the last element with `name="id"`.

Comment: @Supericy: Not nesessarily, just make name='action[$row[0]]' and check it in a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the same `name` attribute on every row in the form, so they are being overridden and it's using the last one.

What you could do is either wrap every row in its own form, or you could do something like this, and have only 1 submit button to execute the action on every row:

```
// remove hidden id element

...

echo "<td><select name='action[" . $row[0] . "]'>"

...
// remove submit button in the loop, but add it after the while loop
...

if (isset($_POST['action']))
{
    foreach ($_POST['action'] as $id => $action)
    {
        if ($action !== 'choose')
        {
            // do action on the id;
            echo $id . " -> " . $action . "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You put every ID in the form, which results in the CGI to send something like this: id=1, id=2, id=3, etc. PHP then only reads the last ID and deletes that.

To fix it, give each row its own form.

```
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) { 
 echo "<form method='post'>";
 echo "<tr><input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row[0]."'>";
 echo "<td>".$row[0]."</td>";
 //echo "<td>".$row[1]."</td>";
 echo "<td>".$row[2]."</td>";
 //echo "<td>".$row[3]."</td>";
// echo "<td>".$row[4]."</td>";
 echo "<td><select name='action'>
             <option value='choose'>Choose..</option>
             <option value='delete'> Delete </option>
             <option value='enable'> Enable </option>
             <option value='block'> Block</option>
        </select></td>";
   echo "</tr>";
   echo "</form>";
 }
 echo "<br><input type='submit' name='submit'></table>";
```

Comment: yes, it is ok now, but now it gives buttons for all records, I need only one. have idea, how to achieve that? thanks